# Returning size of files based on selected date range

Tags: c#

I have a function where it suppose to return size of files within specified range, however, it goes thru all of the files in the directory and not those between date ranges, using linq method: is this even correct way of doing it?

```
public static long fileSize(string source_path)
{
     return new DirectoryInfo(source_path)
             .EnumerateFiles("*.SS*")
             .Where(file => file.CreationTime < dt.AddMonths(-2))
             .Sum(file => file.Length);
}
```

Comment: What date range do you want? As it stands your query will return all files created 2 months before the date stored in `dt`. Is this correct? What value does `dt` hold?

Comment: Actually everything older than 2 months: so dt is Now time.

Comment: Have you checked the intermediate steps of the linq chain to make sure that each one returns the correct result?

Comment: IF `dt` really should be DateTime.Now then replace `dt` with `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2))`

Comment: Ignore my previous answer; I've spent quite a bit of time re-producing the issue and solving it. See my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I've just spent a little time trialling your code.

I couldn't see *why* it wouldn't work, so I split out the code into separate lines. It appears that the long Linq function is confusing itself.

Below is what worked for me.

It is essentially exactly the same as what you were doing before, just declaring some local variables as way-points to make sure things are as they should be at certain points:

```
public static long FileSize(string path)
{
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var allFiles = di.EnumerateFiles(); // Enter your filter "*.SS" or whatever

    var beforeDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2);

    var olderThan2Months = allFiles.Where(x => x.CreationTime < beforeDate);

    return olderThan2Months.Sum(x => x.Length);
}
```

**This worked a charm for me** (obviously you can change the variables to more meaningful names).

Here's a sample screenshot of the above code working
(I only used Downloads folder, and didn't filter the files):

[image: Sample screenshot!]

I used the above code to filter by older than 2 months, and a "GetAll" to compare the 2 and make sure it worked - trust me I made *sure* it does :)

Hope this helps!